# Get total amount of tokens received from a specific address using Web3.js

Tags: web3js

in a scenario, **WalletA** is receiving **TokenB** in a regular basis from **AddressC**.
AddressC only sends TokenB, nothing else.

in etherscan or bscscan it is simple to see how much of TokenB is received in WalletA and "from" field is there so you can do some math to get total.

How can this be done using web3? I couldn't find any relevant api call in web3 documents.
I can get total balance of TokenB in WalletA by web3.js but I need the count of tokens **only** sent from AddressC.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [ERC-20](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md) standard, each token transfer emits a `Transfer()` event log, containing the sender address, receiver address and token amount.

You can get the past event logs using the `web3js` general method [web3.eth.getPastLogs()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-eth.html#getpastlogs), encode the inputs and decode the outputs.

Or you can supply ABI JSON of the contract (it's enough to use just the `Transfer()` event definition in this case) and use the `web3js` method [web3.eth.Contract.getPastEvents()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents), which encodes the inputs and decodes the outputs for you based on the provided ABI JSON.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('<provider_url>');

const walletA = '0x3cd751e6b0078be393132286c442345e5dc49699'; // sender
const tokenB = '0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7'; // token contract address
const addressC = '0xd5895011F887A842289E47F3b5491954aC7ce0DF'; // receiver

// just the Transfer() event definition is sufficient in this case
const abiJson = [{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}];
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiJson, tokenB);

const fromBlock = 10000000;
const toBlock = 13453500;
const blockCountIteration = 5000;

const run = async () => {
    let totalTokensTranferred = 0;

    for (let i = fromBlock; i <= (toBlock - blockCountIteration); i += blockCountIteration) {
        //console.log("Requesting from block", i, "to block ", i + blockCountIteration - 1);
        const pastEvents = await contract.getPastEvents('Transfer', {
            'filter': {
                'from': walletA,
                'to': addressC,
            },
            'fromBlock': i,
            'toBlock': i + blockCountIteration - 1,
        });
    }

    for (let pastEvent of pastEvents) {
        totalTokensTranferred += parseInt(pastEvent.returnValues.value);
    }

    console.log(totalTokensTranferred);
}

run();
```

Comment: that second "fromblock" should be "toblock" I assume and with that I can get an output with this code but since I am getting this error, I dunno if the result is true or not. 
///// 
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned error: exceed maximum block range: 5000 
/////  
my fromblock is the block which token is created and toblock is current block, it is definitely higher than 5000 blocks. is there any workaround to override that?

Comment: @mhmd Thanks, I fixed it in my answer... The "exceed maximum block range" error message comes from your RPC provider (Infura or similar). You can always use a self-hosted node that doesn't impose these limits, otherwise you'll need to look for a provider that offers the limits within your needs.

Comment: I am using web3 on bsc with this provider   web3 = new Web3('https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'); ///// do you know any other provider for bsc with no block range limit?

Comment: or maybe can I run it through a loop for every 5000 blocks? or it has some limitations too?

Comment: @mhmd I'm not aware of any 3rd party BSC providers, apart from the "official" ones listed in their [devs page](https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/rpc.html). Running in a synchonous loop, waiting for each batch to process, might help, but then you might run into other rate limits such as total number of requests per minute. For this scale, I'd really recommend to run your [own fullnode](https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/fullnode.html) that doesn't impose any limits.

Comment: it is a small project and cannot afford a vps for own fullnode.. so maybe I can test the loop. can you show me how to this loop in that code plz?

Comment: @mhmd I edited the answer to iterate the requests for each 5k blocks.

Comment: I am not expert in js but i think there should be a change in line: const pastEvents = ....

Comment: @mhmd The `const pastEvents` redefinition within the loop is not a syntax error, just redeclaring the constant in each iteration (not accessible in higher scopes), which is a bit more memory-heavy compared to reassigning it to a variable (`let pastEvents` outside the loop, and `pastEvents = ...` inside the loop). I was simply aiming for an easy way to extend the previously existing code.